# If check with nullable boolean and elvis operator fails inspection check, why?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, elvis-operator

in Android Studio I wrote the following in a function:

```
if (startTimes.value?.containsKey(name)?:false) {
    return startTimes?.value?.get(name)
}
```

Android Studio highlights the contents of the `if` with a warning with the message `Equality check should be used instead of elvis for nullable boolean check` and suggests I replace it with:

```
if (startTimes.value?.containsKey(name) == true) {
    return startTimes?.value?.get(name)
}
```

Why is the second preferred by the IDE? As far as I can tell they're logically the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking nullable boolean against `true` or `false` is an ["official" Kotlin idiom](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/idioms.html#nullable-boolean):

> #### Nullable Boolean
>
> ```
> val b: Boolean? = ... 
> if (b == true) {
>     ... 
> } else {
>     // `b` is false or null 
> }
> ```

Here is [the relevant discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-the-idiom-for-checking-nullable-booleans-helpful/8238) regarding the idiom, including opinions for and against it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is two steps. It does a null check and then evaluates to a value. The second evaluates the value directly.

Personally, I think the second is much easier to reason about.

*"Is x or else if x is null then false, true?"*

versus

*"Is x exactly true?"*

Aside from that, there are some idioms that the compiler tries to push on you, I think in an effort to make code more readable in general. If most people use the same idioms, it's easier to read each others' code.